# invalid column name in C#

Tags: c#

I am using the following query to update the record in SQL C#.

But I'm getting error:

> invalid column name P1

where `P1` is the parameter of string datatype, who's record is to be updated.

```
string SQl_Update="update dbo.tb_patient set name =patientname ,age= patientcontact where id=P1";
```

Answer (score 0):

check with column `name` .

This column must be different in database or this column might not be present in database.

Please check your table field names and fields in your update query.

If you are trying to use parametrized query put @ before your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

if those three values are parameters, it should be written with `@`,

```
string SQl_Update = @"UPDATE dbo.tb_patient 
                      SET    name = @patientname,
                             age = @patientcontact 
                      WHERE  id = @P1";
```

and in your command object, set the values for each parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `P1` inside single quotes (`'`).

Comment: It'd be nice if you could explain why this solves the problem of the OP.